# Strange behaviour with for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was using the for loop to display items, but I don't know what's wrong going on.

If my array length is 3 then loop repeating 9 times.
If 2 it was repeating 4 times.

I don't know what's happening.

Where am I going wrong?

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
  getOrg(list[i]).fetch({}).$promise.then(function (value) {
    $scope.displayItem = value.data[0];
    console.clear();
    console.info($scope.displayItem);
    var data = {
      'id' : $scope.displayItem.id,
      'item':$scope.displayItem.displayConfig[0].propertyValue
    };
    $scope.displayItems.push(data);
    $scope.displayItems = $scope.displayItem.displayConfig[0].propertyValue;
    console.info($scope.displayItems);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your call to `getOrg(list[i]).fetch({})` looks suspicious.  Perhaps it is somehow changing the length of the list inside the loop?

Comment: why minus the lenght here "i<list.length--",and does function "getOrg" will change the list length?

Comment: Post your code for the `getOrg()` function.

Comment: getOrg() is service. based on id i am fetching from server

Comment: I don't think this code can behave the way you're describing it. `getOrg` is unlikely to change the list's length since it doesn't have access to said list, just to an element. I suspect that the code is just being invoked twice. The why I can't know since I only can see the for loop. Can you show the whole code please?

Comment: i am using data-ng-init() <li class="tag" ng-repeat="lists in selecteditemslist track by $index" ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedIndex}" data-ng-init="display(selecteditemslist,searchid)"> . and also here one problem is there i.e, without 'selecteditemslist' ng-init not getting invoked but no need to repeat selecteditemslist in ng-repeat. . how can i get selecteditemslist without using ng-repeat

Comment: from controller to directive array was getting like this [hai] [hai, hello] [hai,hello,hey] insted of [hai,hello,hey]. so for loop getting repeated many times. how can i restrict  this problem. please help me friends insted of getting like this  [hai] [hai, hello] [hai,hello,hey]  just my controller should pass [hai,hello,hey]